# Rails massive data upload and nested records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to update a lot of data to mysql (~100Mio records!). Some records already exists, some have to be created. I also have to create some nested resources for each record.
I know the activerecord-import gem but as far as i know it can't handle nested records (or only with ugly workarounds). The issue is that I dont know the ID's for all nested records before they are created - and creating them in single queries takes time.

So lets say there is a model called Post and can have many Comments. My current code looks like this:

```
Post.transaction do
import_posts.each do |import_post|
  post = Post.find_or_initialize_by(somevalue: import_post['somevalue']
  post.text = import_post['text']
  import_post['comments'].each do |import_comment|
    comment = post.comments.find_or_initialize_by(someothervalue: import_comment['someothervalue'])
    comment.text = import_comment['text']
  end
  post.save(validate: false) #Dont need validation - saves some time
end
end
```

This is just an example and it works but its far away from 'damn fast'. Are there any ideas how to speed up the data upload? Am I totally wrong?

Im working with Rails5 and ruby 2.4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indeed, doing this in Ruby is very slow, but you get the convenience of the ActiveRecord methods. You can do it in SQL, but you have to reproduce the `find_or_initialize_by` method and id incrementing. This takes time, careful testing, and SQL "chops". I typically take the performance hit and use ActiveRecord. Make sure you have table indexes on the `somevalue` and `someothervalue` columns.

Comment: Hi Les, thanks! Indexing saves a lot of time, right. I already had that in place but missed to mention it.